# Как завершить tcp соединение для windows.networking.sockets windows phone 8.1 c#

Tags: c#, сокет, tcp, windows-phone-8.1

Как завершить tcp соединение для windows.networking.sockets windows phone 8.1 c# ?
Когда я делаю `socket.Dispose();` я получаю FIN_WAIT2 вместо нормального завершения.

Answer (score 1):

разобрался. это связано с flush методом StreamWriter`a

```
Stream forWriter = socket.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite();             
writer = new StreamWriter(forWriter);
writer.AutoFlush = true;
```

Поменял StreamWriter на DataWriter, и всё стало хорошо. Единственное вместо FIN WAIT 2 я получаю TIME WAIT, как сделать по феншую, чтобы соединение сразу разрывалось? после `socket.Dispose()`?